# Pandas apply with list output gives ValueError once df contains timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to implement an apply function that returns two values because the calculations are similar and pretty time consuming, so I don't want to do apply twice.
The below is an MWE that is pretty stupid and I know there are easier ways to achieve what this MWE does. My actual function is more complicated, but I already run into an error with this MWE:

So, I got this to work:

```
def function(row):
    return [row.A, row.A/2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(8),
                'B' : np.random.randn(8)})
df[['D','E']] = df.apply(lambda row: function(row), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

However, this does not:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(8),
                'B' : pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=8, freq='H'),
              'C' : np.random.randn(8)})
df2[['D','E']] = df2.apply(lambda row: function(row), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

Instead, it gives me 
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8, 2), indices imply (8, 3)

I don't understand why changing the type of the B column would impact the outcome, it is not even used in the apply function at all?

I guess I could avoid this issue in the example by temporary excluding the date column. However, in my function later I will need to use the date.

Can someone explain me, why this example does not work? What changes by including a TS?

Comment: `df2[['D','E']] = df2[['A', 'B']].apply(...)` works. Is that what you want? Or maybe `df2[['D','E']] = df2[['A', 'C']].apply(...)`...

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso, this would not have worked in my case, since I need to use row.B in my actual function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have `function` return a `pd.Series` instead.  Returning a list is making apply try to fit the list into the existing row.  Returning a `pd.Series` convinces pandas of something different.

```
def function(row):
    return pd.Series([row.A, row.A/2])


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(8),
                    'B' : pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=8, freq='H'),
                    'C' : np.random.randn(8)})
df2[['D','E']] = df2.apply(function, axis=1)

df2
```

[image]

---

***Attempt to explain***

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s

0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

---

```
s.loc[:] = [4, 5, 6]
s

0    4
1    5
2    6
dtype: int64
```

---

```
s.loc[:] = [7, 8]
```

> ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value

Comment: This is exactly what I just came up with. But I still don't quite grasp what's going on...

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso I can't say with certainty, but I think `apply` is checking `type`.  If it's an `array` or `list` it attemps to assign the values to the existing row structure.  If it is a series instead, it just returns the series.  That's not a great explanation.

Comment: @piRSquared YES, thank you, that did the trick for my real function, too. 
Still don't understand the effect though. What do you mean by 'it attempts to assign the values to the existing row structure'? If I use a column of strings instead of TS it works my old way too, even though it is of a different type.

Comment: @grinsbaeckchen I added some content to my post to try and illustrate what is happening.  This isn't exactly accurate, but possibly analogous.

Comment: @piRSquared unfortunately I do not see how that is analogous. 
I create two new columns that are of the same size as the columns before, just not of the same shape as the overall df was. And then one time it works and one time it does not. That's what I don't understand.